# tvOS open VLC URL scheme

Tags: swift, vlc, tvos, url-scheme

I'm trying to open links to unsupported video files (mkv, avi) in VLC player on tvOS (Apple TV) with the URL scheme [provided by VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:IOS/#x-callback-url) but I receive the following error:
*"The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"*.
Is it not supported on tvOS, or are URL schemes on tvOS generally not available?

The same code snipped successfully launches the VLC App on iOS though:

```
if let vlcUrl = URL(string: "vlc-x-callback://x-callback-url/stream?url=\(url)") {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(vlcUrl) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(vlcUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` to your Info.plist?

Comment: Thx for the hint, but yes, I did

Comment: The VLC player app has to expose the scheme `vlc-x-callback://`. Is there anywhere stating that they do? If they do on iOS it doesn't mean they do on tvOS, different `info.plist`'s.